# Rails convert plain text to html before saving in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

We have a rails app and messages that are sent as json are in plain text:

```
{ "TextBody": "To confirm your subscription to 'Blah ads. Location: Blah. Category: buy and sell.', please click on the following link:\r\n\r\nhttps:\/\/domain.com\/confirm\/jBb62m\r\n\r\n\r\nAs we have no control over the content of the feeds we send, consider adding email@domain.com to your address book or spam whitelist to placate any overexcitable spam filters.\r\n\r\nIf you weren't expecting to receive this email, then simply ignore it and we'll go away."}
```

After parsing the json I have an object so how would I convert this plain text to html or something before saving it to the database.

```
entry.text_body
```

I can't change the view code because there are too many other features of the site using it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**  New question is really how to parse this into HTML in steps.  Replacing \n with 
 and autolinking etc.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442375/escape-non-html-tags-in-plain-text-convert-plain-text-to-html/22442376#22442376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-strip) and the following [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) regex match will render the following:

```
entry.text_body.strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
#=> "To confirm your subscription to 'Blah ads. Location: Blah. Category: buy and
#   sell.', please click on the following link: https://domain.com/confirm/jBb62m
#   As we have no control over the content of the feeds we send, consider adding 
#   email@domain.com to your address book or spam whitelist to placate any
#   overexcitable spam filters. If you weren't expecting to receive this email, 
#   then simply ignore it and we'll go away."
```

**UPDATE**:

First, to replace the `\r\n` and `\n` newline characters with the HTML `<br />` tag a your string, run the following `gsub` regex substitution:

```
'foo\r\nbar'.gsub(/(\r)?\n/, '<br />')
#=> "foo<br />bar"
```

As for the URL conversion to HTML: Rails used to have a view helper called [`auto_link`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link) which would automatically convert a URL to its fully valid markup equivalent. However, this feature has been [deprecated as of Rails 3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/81cfbf4146d3c5a58054b64112b8ce196f2fc061). Fortunately, the functionality was abstracted into a gem called [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

To install the gem, add the following to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails_autolink'
```

Then, import the library (along with its core dependencies) into any script you want the `auto_link` functionality in:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
require 'rails_autolink'

url = 'https://domain.com/confirm/jBb62m'
auto_link(url) # Use auto_link(string).gsub(/\"/, '\'') to escape backslashes
#=> <a href='https://domain.com/confirm/jBb62m'>https://domain.com/confirm/jBb62m</a>

email = 'email@domain.com'
auto_link(email)
#=> <a href='mailto:email@domain.com'>email@domain.com</a>
```

**SUMMARY**:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
require 'rails_autolink'

auto_link(entry.text_body.gsub(/(\r)?\n/, '<br />').strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' '))
#=> "To confirm your subscription to 'Blah ads. Location: Blah. Category: buy 
#   and sell.', please click on the following link:<br /><br /><a 
#   href=\"https://domain.com/confirm/jBb62m\">https://domain.com/confirm/jBb62m
#   </a><br /><br /><br />As we have no control over the content of the feeds we 
#   send, consider adding <a href=\"mailto:email@domain.com\">email@domain.com</a> 
#   to your address book or spam whitelist to placate any overexcitable spam filters.
#   <br /><br />If you weren't expecting to receive this email, then simply ignore 
#   it and we'll go away."
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to evince what you're trying to get at without an example. Can you update your question to show what string you'd like to be storing?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to format \n to <br/> and links to <a href="link">link</a> if possible.

Comment: Please see my update. It should walk you through the steps needed to achieve precisely what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks alot for your thorough answer! I really appreciate when experienced guys take the time to help noobs out.

Comment: Happy it helped. FWIW, if this answer was particularly useful/enlightening, you may want to consider upvoting it so as to highlight its utility to other readers.